# Does the Long Leg of the Grounding Clip go Inside or Outside of the Electrical Box?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I have a model #GEE-B10-10 Grounding Clip that I'm not sure how to install. Does the long leg go on the outside or on the inside of the electrical box?

[image: profile pic of grounding clip]

Long side:

[image: long side of the grounding clip]

Short side:

[image: short side of the grounding clip]

Comment: Your picture doesn't show it but normally one side has a groove where the wire rests when clipped. That side would go inside the box then, yes?

Comment: Jimmy Fix-it I added more pics. So the long side goes in the electrical box and the wire get bent down on top of the long side, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted the company. The long side goes inside the box.

Answer (score 1):

On yours the short side goes inside the notch jimmy is commenting on is the tab the wire is held under that. That angle is hard to see but the ones I use loop a bit further.

Comment: This answer would benefit from breaking the first sentence into three. I had a lot of trouble figuring out what you’re trying to say.

Comment: Ed, Thanks of the comment, but I didn't understand. I've added more pics.

Comment: The short side inside the box. The long side is flat it goes on the outside.